# awk to remove block of text containing a string

Tags: awk

I have a text file with blocks of text separated by blank lines.I would like to remove an entire block of text if it contains a string.

The following is working nicely however it leaves the resulting file as a binary file in gawk 3.1.8. while in **gawk 4.1.0** it works ok. What did I miss?

```
awk -vRS= '$0!~/'$exc'/{print $0RT}' $SDIR/PACKAGES.TXT > $SDIR/PACKAGES2.TXT
```

The code will only run on slackware. Here is a sample of the text file.

```
PACKAGE NAME:  gv-3.7.3-i486-2.txz
PACKAGE LOCATION:  ./slackware/xap
PACKAGE SIZE (compressed):  196 K
PACKAGE SIZE (uncompressed):  590 K
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
gv: gv (PS/PDF file viewer)
gv:
gv: gv is a PostScript and PDF previewer.  It allows users to view and
gv: navigate through PostScript and PDF documents on an X display by 
gv: providing a user interface for the ghostscript interpreter.
gv:
gv: gv was written by Johannes Plass, using the source code for Tim
gv: Theisen's ghostview 1.5 as a starting point.
gv:


PACKAGE NAME:  gvfs-1.12.3-i486-2.txz
PACKAGE LOCATION:  ./slackware/l
PACKAGE SIZE (compressed):  1096 K
PACKAGE SIZE (uncompressed):  7100 K
PACKAGE DESCRIPTION:
gvfs: gvfs (glib virtual filesystems)
gvfs:
gvfs: gvfs is a userspace virtual filesystem designed to work with the I/O
gvfs: abstractions of libgio (a library included in the glib2 package).
gvfs: It installs several modules that are automatically used by applications
gvfs: that use the libgio API.  There is also fuse support that allows
gvfs: applications not using gio to access the gvfs filesystems.
gvfs:
```

Comment: UPDATE: BINMODE appears to only be for OS/2 and DOS. My workaround is to hold the output in a variable, and then use printf to create a text file, but I would still like to know WHY this anomaly(?) occurs.

Comment: I can discern no difference in behaviour between gawk-3.1.8 and 4.1.0 on a selection of `PACKAGES.TXT` I have lying around. How so "binary"? Be aware some pkg entries (possibly `cmake`) have DOS CR/LF line endings, and many contain non-ASCII characters (at least `cupsddk`,`kio-mtp` and `aspell-xx` dictionaries).